# Using an itemprop from one itemtype in another itemtype

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I just started adding Microdata to the product pages of an online retailer. I'm using Schema.org’s `Product` type and at this point I'm only referencing product `manufacturer`, `name` and `description`. Google has picked up that this site now has structured data and is listing the pages (and with no errors).

I have a URL on the product pages that links to more items by the same manufacturer. I would like to markup this URL on each page but the property in the type for `Product` doesn't seem applicable. The description for `url` in `Product` seems to indicate it's a URL to the product and of course I'm already on that product and am linking to related products.

I came across the property `relatedLink` from `WebPage` that seemed more applicable to my reference so my questions are:

1. Can I use the property `url` from `Product` for the type of URL I am referencing?
2. If it's more applicable to use `relatedlink` (or a different property) do I have to specify that the type for that property is `CreativeWork`? My concern is that while that property might be more applicable the type it comes from is definitely not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use `url`. As you rightly point out, the [`url` property](http://schema.org/url) is for the URL of the current item (i.e., the product), and not for URLs of related items.

While the definition of the [`relatedLink` property](http://schema.org/relatedLink) seems to be appropriate for your case, this property can only be used for [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) items (and its sub-types), not for [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product). With [some exceptions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/69598/17633), you may only use the properties that are listed in the table for that type.

If the link targets are also `Product` items, you could use one of these properties:

- [`isRelatedTo`](http://schema.org/isRelatedTo):

  > A pointer to another, somehow related product (or multiple products)
- [`isSimilarTo`](http://schema.org/isSimilarTo):

  > A pointer to another, functionally similar product (or multiple products).

Comment: This is great. Thank you. This brings up a related question. I saw these properties but because the "On Types" allocation didn't explicitly say these could be used for URLs (Just says "Product") does that mean a lot of these properties can be used in a variety of tags like <a>, <div>, <span>, etc.? In the case of isRelatedTo and isSimilarTo I thought they were used to markup related products that are in text format as opposed to linking to another page of similar products. (Ex. Check out these other great <span itemprop="isRelatedTo">mittens</span>).

Comment: @Karen: Yes, Schema.org expects that these properties refer to another `Product` item, so instead of linking directly to the page, you may want to create another `Product` item and use its `url` property: `<span itemprop="isRelatedTo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"><a href="/product-2" itemprop="url">Related product 2</a></span>`

Comment: Thanks! I just re-read the Product properties and found "additionalType" which acts upon a URL and seems to suggest it can be used on related items (or items of a similar collection). Would this be applicable? I tested the page in the markup helper and it seemed to come up as desired (meaning no errors) but that does not mean I used the property correctly. :-)

Comment: @Karen: I’m not sure I understand how exactly you’d want to use `additionalType` here. You could create a new question about this, giving more details, if you like.

Comment: As mentioned I have products pages with links in each page to similar/related products. I would prefer to have an itemprop that I can use directly on the <a href> tags instead of wrapping the URLs in an itemprop. If I understood your comments correctly issimilarto or isrelatedto would have to be wrapped around the URLs. If I understand additionaltype it sounds like it does the same thing but can be placed directly on the URL. Ex: <a href="http://www.mystore.com/more-hat-styles" itemprop="additionalType">More Hats</a>. Is this correct or should I use issimilarto or isrelatedto instead?

Comment: @Karen: Ah, I see. You can’t use [`additionalType`](http://schema.org/additionalType) like that, as it always applies to the whole item, not to a specific property. So it can be used to say that your `Product` also has a different type (e.g., a product type from a different vocabulary than Schema.org). -- Regarding Schema.org’s "expected types": Creating separate `Product` items for `isRelatedTo`/`isSimilarTo` is recommended, but not required. See ["Expected types vs text"](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#schemaorg_expected). So if you want to, you could directly link to the related products.

Comment: Thanks for this. Now I understand "additionaltype". Thanks also for the page talking about expected types. What's odd is that I originally tried adding issimilarto directly to the <a> tag and the markup tester kept failing hence my above noted comment. I just tried it again and it worked so I must have missed a quote or something. As an example this code exists on a page about wool hats. <h3>Associated Items</h3>
<a title="Related Wool Hats" href="http://www.mystore.com/collections/winter-items/wool%20hat" itemprop="isSimilarTo">More Wool Hats</a> Is this the correct usage?

Comment: @Karen: This should be correct. If you have created your HTML5+Microdata, you could ask for feedback/review on [codereview.se].